# Google analytics Api Removes session on refresh

Tags: laravel, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-client, google-oauth

I have to first of all say I'm really confused with the Googles API and the docs I've tried so many diffrent approaches by now, but do wanna understand it, i have finally found some code there could guide me towards getting it done i just have a little problem, everytime i refresh my page I'm loosing the Session made by Google's api and i dont know why.

```
 $client = new Google_Client();

   $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));
    $client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refreshtoken
// Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
    }        

// Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

    // request user accounts
    $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

   foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
    echo "Account: ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";        
    foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
        //echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WebProperty: ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    

        $views = $wp->getProfiles();
        if (!is_null($views)) {
            foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;View: ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
            }
        }
    }
} // closes account summaries

}
 print_r($_SESSION['token']); 
?>
```

I tried following this article http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/. Also a little extra question what is my next step to retrieve the users analytics data? Hope someone out there aren't as confused as me, and can help. Also im useing Laravel 5.2 as Framework

Comment: I recommend you use this package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics

Comment: I looked at this, and coulndt really figure out how to setup the user authentication, Maybe i'll give it another look

Comment: I spend 2 hours to figure out how to setup it and the bigger problem is the google console UX. I'll try help you. Where you are in the documentation?

Comment: Currently I'm not sure, i read so many diffrent guides etc, that I'm just around but i think i am at the point where i have to refresh the token.(https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) But im not totally sure

Comment: I was talking about spatie/laravel-analytics. I thought you was following it.

Comment: 1 - You add the spatie/laravel-analytics into composer. 2 - Add the service provider. 3 - Publish the config file. 4 - Try follow step by step the docs: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#how-to-obtain-the-credentials-to-communicate-with-google-analytics

Comment: Ah my bad, i will test it again tomorrow, and see if i can get it to work, Thanks so far!

Comment: @Lucas so a fast question, i can see you set the view id in the config files, so when someone are loggin in, how will it know what view to take? I dont want my own sites analytics, but my customers, also how do i set up the auth login?

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/hqumx (You should set just the certification path in config/laravel-analytics.php, a .p12 file, for security purpouse). You got setup and retrive your view analytics data? e. g.: $analyticsData = \Analytics::getVisitorsAndPageViews(7); // last 7 days

Comment: ANALYTICAS_SITE_ID=ga:{YOUR_VIEW_ID} (Account -> Property -> View -> View Settings -> View ID)

Comment: You can set the view ID dinamically for each customer. Now how to do that depends of your problem.

Comment: @Lucas Thanks for the help so far! I got a bit longer but now i get the error :
ErrorException in OAuth2.php line 364:
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
"error" : "invalid_grant"

Comment: Also you have too add the Service email under the Analytics, i really don't see how this can get my customers info when they "login", or am i totally wrong here?

Comment: Can you talk more about "my customers info when they login"?

Comment: @Lucas Yes of course! what i want is when the user are loggin in with the  Google API auth, i can retrive their data and show them there GA statistics using the Oauth, basiclly like this (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) Choose the Google analytics API the user is authenticated and you get their GA stats, like how many session, page views etc, hope it's understandable.

Comment: To authenticate the user using Google Oauth i recommend you another package: https://github.com/laravel/socialite . This package works with many others providers too and it are maintained by Laravel. About your problem i not understand it yet. What data you want to show and for whom?

Comment: maybe this help too: https://tuts.codingo.me/google-oauth-and-laravel-in-60-seconds

Comment: Hmm i think this is only for Google+, FB, and twitter and not the analytics authenticate.

Comment: Yes, it just to clean up your code when using Google Auth2.

Comment: Google Analytics API provides information about the users interation with your application, so i dont think you can separate this data by user.

Comment: Well for example here: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/ You authorize and you get the data from your analytics with the accoint you authorized

Comment: That seems a bit simpler perhaps i should try that out.

Comment: yes. I just dont understand whats your problem. You install the spatie/laravel-analytics, set the configs correctly and get any analytics data about your site or app.

Comment: You pass the data you want for your view and build some charts using Chartjs (i recommend).

Comment: My problems is i dont want my data i want my customer to be able to se their own data, I'm trying to make a place where they can see the most usefull information from their Google analytics / Adwords, and i dont know all their site id's etc.

Comment: Now i understood but i dont know if you can do this. Sorry!

Comment: Hahah No worries, sorry for the bad explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Just use https://github.com/OzanKurt/google-analytics/ it will all be fine. ;)

Comment: I hope this helps mate, I made it as simple as possible.

Comment: Hmm just looking at it, it looks like you only get the data from the inserted analyticsViewId, is this correct, there are no user authentication, so people can sign in, and i can pull their data?

Comment: People can sign in and you can pull their data, but you need the view id.

Comment: Can that change dynamiclly by itself after people are logged in, or would you have too change it manually?

Comment: Oh it's a great point. I will do an update to make it customisable inside code too. Currently its reading directly from the config file. What you have to do is to extend that class and add a `setAnalyticsViewId()` method to that you can edit it.